# How to ensure any drupal contributed module is secure

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal for my website and I always use contributed modules for themes or to extend feature.

I am not sure which tool should I use to scan these modules before applying to my code. Also it is good if you could name some of the software composition analysis tool which show the license information, vulnerable components etc.

Tried looking on Drupal blog but didnt find